# Python record level comparision 2 large delimited files

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have 2 large delimited files.

Help needed in :

a) I need to get the **row count** based on the **key column** for both the files

b) finding the duplicates based on key column in both the files

c) Get the **duplicate count** from both files.

d) Duplicates should be created as **separate file**

e) get the **common records** in both the files.

f) **Sort** ing both the files(common records)

g) Comparing both files after sorting it and get the **mismatch count**.

h) Mismatch records should be created as a separate file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you have to sort your files, you have to load them in memory you could probably do something like :

```
#see @ http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/ for information about sorted containers.
#they are efficient for huge data.
from sortedcontainers import SortedList, SortedDict

file1=SortedList()
file2=SortedList()

delimiter = ";"
commentSign="#"
path1="./data1"
path2="./data2"

def get_values_column(delimited_lines, column_number, delimiter, commentSign):
    values = set()
    for line in delimited_lines:
        if line[0] != commentSign:
            fields = line.split(delimiter)
            values.add(fields[column_number])
    return values

def count_not_in_other(collection1, collection2):
    uniq1 = []
    uniq2 = []
    for elem in collection1:
        if elem not in collection2:
            uniq1.append(elem)

    for elem in collection2:
        if elem not in collection1:
            uniq2.append(elem)

    return (uniq1,uniq2)

def from_line_list_to_line_count(line_list):
    lines = SortedDict()

    for line in line_list:
        if line not in lines.keys():
            lines[line] = 0
        lines[line] += 1

    return lines

def duplicated_lines(line_list):
    lines_count = from_line_list_to_line_count(line_list)
    return list(filter( lambda x: lines_count[x]>1, lines_count.keys()))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with open(path1, "r") as io1, open(path2,"r") as io2 :
        #copy the file in memory and sort them.
        for line in io1:
            file1.add(line)

        for line in io2:
            file2.add(line)

    with open(path1, "w") as io1, open(path2,"w") as io2 :
        #rewrite sorted files
        for line in file1:
            io1.write(line)

        for line in file2:
            io2.write(line)

        print("There is {0} different key value in {1}".format(len(get_values_column(file1, 0, delimiter, commentSign)), path1))
        print("There is {0} different key value in {1}".format(len(get_values_column(file2, 0, delimiter, commentSign)), path2))

        uniques = count_not_in_other(file1, file2)
        print("There is {0} lines present in file1 that are not present in file2".format(len(uniques[0])))
        print("There is {0} lines present in file2 that are not present in file1".format(len(uniques[1])))


        print("file1 duplicated lines are : {0}".format(duplicated_lines(file1)))
        print("file2 duplicated lines are : {0}".format(duplicated_lines(file2)))
```

I used it with this data :
data1

```
#id; name; value
10; foo; 100
10; foo; 100
10; foo; 101
11; foo; 50
13; bar; 500
```

data2

```
#id; name; value
10; foo; 100
11; foo; 50
13; bar; 500
18; bar foo; 46
10; foo; 100
10; foo; 101
18; bar foo; 46
```

As you ask for a very complete job without giving any clue about what you tried before, I'll let you with only this. Try to understand the code and complete it. For now you sort your file and get the (number of) key for each file.

NB : I'm not affiliated in any way to the sortedcontainers library.

Comment: thanks...i got it....Now i left with duplicate count and Mismatch count.. Duplicate Count should be based on the #id and for mismatch it should be like element to element ..something it should look  like  Mismatch on column NAME, row number 5 , Source value is : 13 and Target value is : 10